# Instantiating Vanilla JS Class in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, es6-class

For the life of me, can't find the answer myself having scoured...

---

I have a *PURE JAVASCRIPT CLASS* that instantiates to create cookies.  However, **I'm not sure of how to instantiate a vanilla JS class in React**.

In that, *is it best to assign the instance to a component's state?*  Or can I avoid that?

Further, it doesn't seem to make sense to pass the class as a prop.

Here's the general Structure of What I'm trying to do:

`"Cookies" (Van. JS Class)  --->  "new Cookies()" in "Root.jsx" (React Component)`

---

Apologies, if this seems rudimentary.  I'm new to React.

Thanks, in advance, for your help!

-CookieMonster

### Here's a gist of what I am thinking...

Cookies Class
    import Cookies from 'js-cookie';

```
export default class Cookies {
constructor(){
    this.cookieName='hadTreatment';
    this.cookieVal='';
}

initCookie() {
    if (getCookie() == '') {
        setCookie('true');
    } else {
        cookieVal = '';
    }
}

setCookie(cv) {
    Cookies.set(cookieName, cv, { expires: 7 });
}

getCookie() {
    console.log(Cookies.get(cookieVal));
    return Cookies.get(cookieName);
}
```

}

---

```
(Abridged) "Root" Component Class
class Root extends Component {
componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.state.oddDialogLen);
    this.handleCookies();
}
 handleCookies(){
    let c = (this.state.cookies instanceof CookieMonster) ? this.state.cookies : new CookieMonster();
    this.setState({
        cookies: c
    });
}

render() {

    if(this.state.renderDrip == true && this.state.cookies.getCookie == ''){
        return (
            <Story updateRenderDrip={this.updateRenderDrip} />
        )
    }
    return (<Home />)
    }
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: @Colin Addded a gist of what I've written or, rather, thinking of writing.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classes are just special functions, and you are creating new objects when you instantiate them. Depending on what you need to do, you may store them as state and pass as props, destruct them into primitive state variables, or use something like Redux and not deal with them at all.

React is primarily a view library and you can keep data regarding the UI state of your application. But you may store some other data regarding application logic as long as its flow is not too complicated. If you can post your Cookie class or elaborate on what does it contain, I might help better. What I meant by destructing into primitive variables is something like that: Let's say your cookie has a name and an expiration date. You can store a state variable called `cookie: new Cookie(cookie)` or better two variables: `cookieName: cookie.name`, `cookieExpirationDate = cookie.expirationDate`. Or even better you can just check for specific cookie and check its expiration date in your consturctor and set a boolean state variable `hasVisitedBefore` depending on the result.

Comment: Thanks. The case is: I'm creating a cookie that would skip an "introduction" (a React component called "Story") to site if the user has visited it previously. Thus redirecting directly to a "Home" component. Both "Home" and "Story" are conditional components of a "Root" component. 

In brief, would it be better practice to simply assign the instance to the state? 

New to React, abs virgin to Redux. ;-)

Too, I'm not sure what you mean by "destruct" instances into primitive state variables. Mind elaborating?

Thanks!

Comment: Ankari I've posted code above, of what I was considering using. Thanks!

Comment: Gotcha on the destructing bit.

Comment: Ali, I was using my phone. Didn't meant to call you "Ankari". Ha. :-)

Thank you!